# Calculating probability given mean and variance without using z-score

Tags: probability, self-study

i need to calculate the probability  $P(X<-0.03)$ with $E(X)=0.01$ and $Var(X)=0.04$ without knowing the distribution. Only thing I know is that $X$ is symmetrically and continously distributed.

I already calculated the probability under the assumption that $X$ is normally distributed which is $P(X<-0.03) = 0.0228$.

But that assumption was revoked in this sub-task.
The correct result is given: $0.125$.

Comment: Are you sure that you know nothing about the distribution? That seems necessary to get an exact value (rather than a bound). What does the problem statement say?

Comment: I think that i kinda need a bound instead of the exact probability. As i said the only information given is that $X$ is symmetrically and continously distributed with $E(X) = 0.01$ and $Var(X)=0.04$ without assuming a specific distribution - I thought about using Tschebyscheff but it it gives me an area around $E(X)$ instead $P(X<-0.03)$ afaik

Comment: Are you sure the Var(X) doesn't equal 0.0004?

Comment: Or $0.0004$ probably?

Comment: It says that $V(X)=4$%^2  ... oh i shouldn't have ignored the Percent-sign being squared i think

Comment: If SD(X)=0.04 then the bound for Chebyshev is 0.5. Not much help there.

Comment: No, youre right it is 4%^2 which is equal to 0.0004

Comment: 4%^2 = 0.04^2 = 0.0016. But 4% x 10^-2 = 0.0004. Which is it? The second is obviously more helpful.

Comment: Since the task says E(X) = 1% which is obviously 0.01 and V(X) = 4%^2 i assume that it is 4*(1/100)^2

Comment: I added a solution assuming Var(X)=0.0004 (which would make sense but is a weird way to write it) below. I get your logic, but as a mathematician I'd read 4%^2 as (4/100)^2 = 16/10000 = 0.0016. But if they view % as a unit, I guess this makes sense.

Comment: Yea i get it its pretty weird but weve been taught to handle it as a unit thus i think that your answer is correct, thanks alot.

Comment: No worries. Everyone does it differently. I always teach my students that you can't do arithmetic with a percent sign and you should always think of those as their fractional or decimal equivalent. I guess there's no right way as long as people can communicate what they're working with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Chebyshev's Rule, at least 75% of the values fall within two standard deviations of the mean. Since $\mu = 0.01$ and if $\mbox{Var}(X)=0.0004$, then $\sigma = 0.02$ and

$P(0.01-2(0.02) < X < 0.01 + 2(0.02)) = P(-0.03 < X < 0.05) \geq 0.75$

If so, $P(X<-0.03) \leq 0.125$. I don't see how you get equality without further information.

Edit: Changed upper bound from 0.03 to 0.05

Comment: $\sigma=0.2$ if $\sigma^2=0.04$

Comment: Sorry, was being hasty. Edited.

Comment: $k\neq 2$ i'm afraid.